# Mysql Programm to mobile

Tags: mysql, html, mobile, web-applications

I made a Web Program which runs perfect on my localhost.
Now I want to bring it in the App Store and Google Playstore.

I hope someone of you can give me a tip which Plattform I should use as a Server.

T thought about azure or firebase.
But by firebase i have to Change my whole code because of tht nosql and it is not really possbile to make dynmaic pages.

on azure I only can bring it on the Marketplace.

does anyone know other pltfforms?

Answer (score 0):

Ionic / Cordova / Phongap / Appcelerator are all names to look up for building a hybrid app and distributing to app stores.

Amazon EC2 or RDS can host a database for you which the app can connect to, I'm sure there are many others.